# Duplicate entry whilst using Insert in preparedStatment and retrieving previous data whilst matching results

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, duplicates, prepared-statement

```
public int addUsers(int USER_ID,String FIRST_NAME,String LAST_NAME,String PASSWORD,String             USERNAME,String USER_PERMISSION) throws SQLException {

    Connection  conn = null;

    conn = getConnectivity(conn) ;

    getConnectivity(conn);

    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * from USER_DETAILS";
    PreparedStatement pres = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);
    ResultSet rs1 = pres.executeQuery(); 

        if(rs1.next()){
            String Username =   rs1.getString(5);


            System.out.println("username found "+Username);


            System.out.println("username input " + USERNAME);
            System.out.println("password input " + PASSWORD);
            if (Username.equals(USERNAME)){

                System.out.println("Username already exists");
                conn.close();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("FOUND ELSE");
                String sql = "INSERT INTO USER_DETAILS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, USER_ID);
                ps.setString(2, FIRST_NAME);
                ps.setString(3,LAST_NAME);
                ps.setString(4,PASSWORD);
                ps.setString(5,USERNAME);
                ps.setString(6,USER_PERMISSION);
                int result = ps.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println(result);

            }

        }

    conn.close();

    return USER_ID;
}
```

and for login I am using

```
public boolean login(String USERNAME, String PASSWORD) throws SQLException
{
    boolean result = false;
    Connection  conn = null;

    conn = getConnectivity(conn) ;


    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * from USER_DETAILS";
    PreparedStatement pres = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);
    ResultSet rs1 = pres.executeQuery(); 

    if(rs1.next()){
        String Username =   rs1.getString(5);
        String Password =   rs1.getString(4);
        String UserPermission = rs1.getString(6);

        System.out.println("username found "+Username);


        System.out.println("username input " + USERNAME);
        System.out.println("password input " + PASSWORD);

        if (Username.equalsIgnoreCase(USERNAME) && Password.equalsIgnoreCase(PASSWORD) &&     UserPermission.equalsIgnoreCase("blocked")){

            System.out.println("User Logged in");
            conn.close();
        }
        System.out.println("gets out of the code");

    }
    conn.close();
    return result;
}
```

first of all it is allowing to enter more than one entry, so duplicates occurring regardless of my if statement, and when i add fresh new data and try to see I can log in, it still compares with previously added data and does not work. Can someone see what am i doing wrong here. please thanks

below is the system print out i get ,

```
Connection Valid
username found kamran    (don't know why he is still picking up this column)
username input macbook   (these i have already in my database)
password input hello     (these i have already in my database)
gets out of the code   

Connection Valid
Connection Valid

username found kamran   (don't know why he is still picking up this column)
username input macho    (these i have already in my database)
password input hello    (these i have already in my database)
FOUND ELSE              (dont know why it adds data when they already exist in database)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense: you are querying for **all** users and only checking the first returned user if it matches. Of course that is going to fail if the first returned user doesn't match: in `addUsers` you will try to add the user if the first user returned doesn't match, in `login` a user can only login if it is the first user.

You need to use a `WHERE` clause to only request the user you want to check:

```
// Note: this assumes a case insensitive collation
String sqlSelect = "SELECT * from USER_DETAILS WHERE username = ?";
try (PreparedStatement pres = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect)) {
    pres.setString(1, USERNAME);
    try (ResultSet rs1 = pres.executeQuery()) {
        if (!rs1.next) {
            // user doesn't exist yet, create...
        }
    }
}
```

You need to do something similar for `login` (but then with `if (rs1.next())` instead).

There are more problems with your current code: you are storing plaintext passwords: you should really hash them with a strong password hash like PBKDF2. Also please follow the java naming conventions. Variables and parameters are camelcase so not `USERNAME` but `username` (or `userName`), not `UserPermission`, but `userPermission`. This improves the readability for people who are used to the java naming conventions.

Comment: thanks buddy, make sense. I shall take care of it in future. Also the problem is solved